# sql, delete rows only when affected with a previous UPDATE command

Tags: sql, delete-row

I only want to update 1 row (id) and only IF the status is == to stat

```
UPDATE link_list SET status=0 WHERE id=@id AND status=@stat;
```

Now i want to delete all rows but ONLY if the above was affected, how do i change the below to only delete if the above was affected?

```
DELETE link_list WHERE linkId=@id;
```

Comment: use after update trigger, it might help

Comment: It would be helpful to tag your question with the brand of RDBMS you use.  "sql" does not specify the brand, only the language.

Answer (score 3):

What DB?

In datbases that support OUTPUT clause (SQL Server, ORacle, I think DB2) is easy:

```
UPDATE link_list SET status=0 
OUTPUT @linkID= DELETED.@id
WHERE id=@id AND status=@stat;

DELETE link_list WHERE linkId=@linkID;
```

Another option is to use a foriegn key constraint with ON DELETE CASCADE and let the engine do the delete for you.

Comment: `OUTPUT` is supported by Oracle?  I've only seen the functionality called `RETURNING`: http://www.lattimore.id.au/2006/04/06/oracle-returning-clause/

Comment: You're right, I slipped in Oracle as having OUTPUT syntax. I think though the RETURNING can be use din the same fashion.

Comment: @Remus: Yep - the usual, same functionality using different syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I second the comment by @Rahuls suggesting using a trigger.  Here's another alternative:

```
UPDATE link_list SET status=0, id=(@affectedid:=id) WHERE id=@id AND status=@stat;

DELETE link_list WHERE linkId = @affectedid;
```

The `@affectedid` user variable should be NULL if no rows were matched, so the `DELETE` will be a no-op.  But if you are likely to do this more than once in a given session, the value of `@affectedid` could carry over from an earlier update, so it would be prudent to set it to NULL explicitly.

NB: I have not tested this, so be careful and test thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

You can only delete rows where the status is 0 - you cannot directly say if that was in the last update

To delete where status is 0

```
DELETE link_list WHERE linkId=@id and statua = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking `@@rowcount`, which gives you the number of rows affected by the previous statement.

Comment: That's assuming SQL Server; SQL%ROWCOUNT if you are using Oracle.